# pretty complex Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I did a lot of research, but apparently my Regex skills are not enough to solve this, so I come to humbly ask for advice.

I have a JS var that gets strings similar to this:

```
"value=8kadctgwqqe0&value=8kaczvfgoyrs&value=8kwkgz2ysm1i"
```

it doesn't have a fixed lenght. it may return 1 or 20 values, there's no way to know.

As you can see, it returns a big sequence of values that are always between "value=" and "&", except for the last one, that has no "&" in the end.
I need to parse that, and get this in the end:

```
8kadctgwqqe0
8kaczvfgoyrs
8kwkgz2ysm1i
```

I don't even know where to start...
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it possible for the strings between `value=` and `&` to ever contain either `"value="` or `"&"` in them? If so, then this gets a lot more complex lol...

Comment: easy way: just append a "&" to the end and do your normal stuff, but a queryString parse would be better in the end...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

personally I would avoid regex for this.

if your string is always in the value=SOMETHING&value=SOMETHINGELSE format use this

```
string.split("value=").join("").split("&")
```

according to [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)  its actually quicker to use this over regex also

```
var string = "value=8kadctgwqqe0&value=8kaczvfgoyrs&value=8kwkgz2ysm1i"
var yourArray = string.split("value=").join("").split("&")
["8kadctgwqqe0", "8kaczvfgoyrs", "8kwkgz2ysm1i"]
```

You may need to add some tests to ensure the correct format of string if you are not sure about it.

Answer (score 2):

The following RegExp/.filter() should do it:

```
'value=8kadctgwqqe0&value=8kaczvfgoyrs&value=8kwkgz2ysm1i'.match(/([^=&]+)/g).filter(function(a){return a!='value'});
```

The `.match()` will grab the separate query values *(and the key names)*. In order to deal with this, we use `.filter()` to remove the `value` results. This will leave it with the correct results.

---

Sometimes it's better to use regular JavaScript string manipulation *(even though this looks like the worst answer)*

`.filter()` is awesome, [more info on it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
/(?:^|&)value=([^&]*)/g
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/pG0lP7/2)

The matches are then stored in the first capture group.

You can now access the capture groups [using this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/432503/67579):

```
var myRegexp = /(?:^|&)value=([^&]*)/g;
var myString = "value=8kadctgwqqe0&value=8kaczvfgoyrs&value=8kwkgz2ysm1i";

match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
while (match != null) {
    console.log(match[1]);
    match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
}
```

If you are interested in the keys as well, you can use:

```
/(?:^|&)([^=&]*)=([^&]*)/g
```

In that case for each iteration, the key can be found in the first match, and the value in the second one:

```
var myRegexp = /(?:^|&)([^&=]*)=([^&]*)/g;
var myString = "value=8kadctgwqqe0&value=8kaczvfgoyrs&value=8kwkgz2ysm1i";

match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
while (match != null) {
    console.log(match[1]); //key
    console.log(match[2]); //value
    match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
}
```

Comment: @RaulRibeiro: if you copy paste the demo, it works on *JSFiddle*, don't see what PHP has to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

This works as well:

```
str.match(/value=([^&]*)/g).join("").split('value=').splice(1)
```